# python runpy.run_module exit code

Tags: python, subprocess, exit, runpy

Is it possible to get the exit code from a module called through runpy.run_module()?

I wish to replace my

    `exit_code = subprocess.call('py -m mymodule')`

with

    `runpy.run_module('mymodule')`

and still get the `exit_code` value.

Where `mymodule` is a directory containing a python script `__main__.py` which just does `sys.exit(1)`

Testing `runpy.run_module('mymodule')` in an interactive shell closes that shell. I could not find any documentation on that behavior. To me it looks like that the difference between using `subprocess.call` and `runpy.run_module` is running it as a program or function. If that is the case then the behavior is explained and it is unlikely that I can use `runpy.run_module` if I need the exit code.
Can anyone confirm this, possibly with a link to some documentation where I could have found it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This morning it hit me, so I tested a solution and it worked:

```
import runpy

try:
    runpy.run_module('mymodule')
except SystemExit as exeption:
    exitcode = exeption.code
else:
    exitcode = 0
```

The catch is that you have to handle every exception thrown in the module. I am only handling the `SystemExit` exception in my example, as it is the only exception that I am interested in.